# Given n numbers, writing a routine to find the largest number between 4 consecutive numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to figure out how to find the largest from the first four numbers in a sequence, then find the largest in the next four numbers in the sequence, etc...

I wrote a function that finds the largest element in an array which is here:

```
double max_array(int n, double array[]){
    double arr[n];
    arr[0] = 0;
    double max;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
           if(arr[0] < array[i])
               arr[0] = array[i];
        }
    max = arr[0];
    return max;
}
```

I believe I can use what I have done here to write a routine to do the latter of that I described but I am not sure how to do this. Perhaps I have to write an entirely new function but I am not sure, any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're right, you can use `max_array` to do it. Iterate through the array by four elements (skip four elements on each iteration) and for each iteration, call `max_array` with `n = 4` and `array` equal to a pointer pointing to the current element.

Comment: @GigaRohan Thank you for the comment, I am still a bit of a novice when it comes to C++ terminology so I don't fully understand. Could you provide an answer that expands on what you just said?

Comment: Anthony D. has provided the code below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if u want to use the function you already have you can do it this way 
create another function that calls the function you already have.

```
double* max_array_vec(int n, double array[]){
    int max_mumber = n/4 + (n%4); // how many max number you will have
    double max[max_number];
    double temp[4];
    arr[0] = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < max_number; i++)
    { 
        std::copy(array+ (3 * i), array+ (3 * (i + 1)), temp);
        max[i] = max_array(4,temp);
    }
    max = arr[0];
    return max;
}
```

but you can make another function that does the entire process and it can be much easier.

Edited second part

```
double *max_array(int n, double *array){
double arr[n/4 + 1] = {-1000, } ;// since ur looking for the biggest number u should initialize tis array with numbers really small like -400 or something like that 
int index = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{ 
   if(i%4 == 0 && i!= 0)
      index++;

   if(arr[index] < array[i])
      arr[index] = array[i];

}
//printf("\n");
//for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
//printf("%f\n ", arr[i]);

return arr;
}
```

the problem was in the fist time i wasnt ignoring when i = 0 that i dont need to increment the index

Comment: Your code for the second part is almost right but something goes wrong assume the array we pass in has these elements: 0
0.5
0.25
0.75
0.125
0.625
0.375
0.875
0.0625
0.5625
0.3125
0.8125

Comment: Then your function returns 0
0.75
0.875

Comment: In other words arr[0] = 0.75, arr[1] = 0.875, arr[2] = 0.8125

Answer (score 1):

This should more or less do what you want. There are multiple results, one for each quad you have in the input array:

```
#include <valarray>
#include <cassert>

std::valarray<double> maxQuads(std::valarray<double> input) {
    assert(!(input.size() % 4)); // The input must contain a multiple of 4 values
    std::valarray<double> output(input.size() / 4);
    for(std::size_t sliceIndex = 0; sliceIndex + 4 < input.size(); sliceIndex += 4) {
        std::slice slice(sliceIndex, 4, 1);
        output[sliceIndex / 4] = std::valarray(input[slice]).max();
    }
    return output;
}

void test() {
    double aTestArray[] = {1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5};
    std::valarray results = maxQuads(std::valarray(aTestArray, 8));
    std::cout << "Max of the first 4: " << results[0];
    std::cout << "Max of the second 4: " << results[1];
}
```

Comment: can your function be used to pass in an array of doubles?

Comment: @Scooby Added an example of how to pass in an array of doubles. You could make a wrapper function to do so if you need to.

Comment: what if I wanted to store the first 4 numbers in an array call V, so V[0] would be the maximum of the first 4 and then V[1] would be the maximum of the second four, could I use what you did to do that?

Comment: in the function `test()` the `results` variable is a valarray containing exactly what you describe. I edited to make this extra clear

Comment: In my compiler I get an error that says Method 'max' could not be resolved

Comment: @Scooby Seems it didnt work out the implicit cast, try the revised code

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could reuse `max_array`:

```
// Assume I have an array 'foo' with N elements.
// In your code, N should be an actual value, like 10, and NOT a variable.

double V[N/4];
int i = 0;
while (i+4 < N) {
    // use the i-th element of foo as the 0-th
    // element of 'array' in max_array.
    double V[i/4] = max_array(4, &(foo[i]));

    i += 4;
}
```

Please note that, with the above code, if N is not a multiple of 4, say, `N = 6`, then the last elements will not be taken into account.

For example, if `foo` is equal to `{ 0.0, 1.0, 1.5, 2.1, 5.0, 10.3 }`, then `V` will only have one element. `{ 2.1 }`.

Comment: You probably want `i += 4` to meet the requirements here.  And boundary case on the last group if N is not a multiple of 4.  Assuming N is a constant here, since VLAs are not part of the C++ standard.

Comment: what if I wanted to store the first 4 numbers in an array call V, so V[0] would be the maximum of the first 4 and then V[1] would be the maximum of the second four, could I use what you did to do that?

Comment: @paddy Ah, thanks. I had put `++i` because I understood "*the next four numbers in the sequence*" to mean "*0th to 3rd, then 1st to 4th, etc.*". Regarding `N`, I had assumed `N` to be a compile-time constant, but after your helpful remark I added a `#define`.

Comment: @Scooby Yea, just declare an array (let's say it's called `maxResults`) of size equal to ceiling of `N/4`, add a second iterator variable `j` and initialize to `0`, then inside the for loop add `maxResults[j] = maxOfFour` and then `j++`.

Comment: @Scooby I've edited my answer so that you have an array `V` which contains the max element of each of the 4 values in the sequence.

Comment: I think I understand but when I try your code I get this error message: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

Comment: @Scooby If, in your code, you have an array called `values`, then you should replace `foo` by `values`, and `N` by the number of elements of `values`. So *do not copy the line* `double foo[N] = /* something */;`. Copy only what is after that, and replace `foo` and `N` by whatever you want in your case.